# column to rows but holding on to common column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
data.frame(group1_a_mu = 10, group1_b_sd = 4, group1_c_xx = 5, group2_a_mu=1, group2_b_sd=2, gorup2_c_xx = 14, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 group1_a_mu group1_b_sd group1_c_xx group2_a_mu group2_b_sd gorup2_c_xx
1       10        4        5        1        2       14
```

and I would like to transform it to this:

```
            mu    sd     xx
group1     10    4     5
group2      1     2    14
```

how can one do that?

Comment: Note, you have a typo in your original data frame, you have `gorup2_c = 14` which should be `group2_c = 14`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following (based on the data from the original post):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(group1_a = 10, group1_b = 4, group1_c = 5, group2_a=1, group2_b=2, group2_c = 14, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    gather(key, val) %>%
    separate(key, c('group_name', 'subgroup_name'), sep = '_') %>%
    spread(subgroup_name, val)

##   group_name  a b  c
## 1     group1 10 4  5
## 2     group2  1 2 14
```

For the situation where there are 2 `_` characters (updated post), the following approach temporarily modifies the `_` character.  The alternative is to use the look ahead or look behind operators in the `separate` regular expression (`sep`).

```
data.frame(group1_a_mu = 10, group1_b_sd = 4, group1_c_xx = 5, group2_a_mu=1, group2_b_sd=2, group2_c_xx = 14, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    gather(key, val) %>%
    mutate(key = sub('_', '|', key)) %>%              ## Temporary change of '_' to '|'
    separate(key, c('group_name', 'subgroup_name'), sep = '_') %>%
    spread(subgroup_name, val) %>%
    mutate(group_name = sub('[|]', '_', group_name))  ## Change back to '_'

##   group_name mu sd xx
## 1   group1_a 10 NA NA
## 2   group1_b NA  4 NA
## 3   group1_c NA NA  5
## 4   group2_a  1 NA NA
## 5   group2_b NA  2 NA
## 6   group2_c NA NA 14
```

Using the positive look behind operator will give the same results.

```
data.frame(group1_a_mu = 10, group1_b_sd = 4, group1_c_xx = 5, group2_a_mu=1, group2_b_sd=2, group2_c_xx = 14, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    gather(key, val) %>%
    separate(key, c('group_name', 'subgroup_name'), sep = '(?<=[a-z])_') %>%
    spread(subgroup_name, val)
```

Comment: thanks steve what if there were 2 "_" in the names? see edit

Comment: The `sep` parameter is a regular expression.  There is likely a way to do this by using the look ahead or look behind operators (I am not sure yet how to do that).  The alternative is to temporarily modify the first `_` to something like `|` then set it back to `_` after the separate.